# Undefined When Retrieving Data from Table With Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to retrieve row id data when a row is clicked on in my table, but I get undefined instead of a string. I have tried many different solutions online by using other methods such as data-links instead of ids, but I run into the same error. I assume there may be something I am missing because my table is generated from a separate php file (below).

```
echo "<tr id='aapl' class= $color>";
echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['stock']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['invested']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['net_worth']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$percent_change}%  </td>";
```

The table is defined in another php file:

```
<table id="stock_table" class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Stock Name</th>
           <th>Ticker</th>
           <th>Invested</th>
           <th>Current Value</th>
           <th>Percent Change</th>
           <th>Sell</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="show_stocks">

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Lastly, the jquery code is defined in the same file as the table and is:

```
$("#show_stocks").click(function(evt) {
  //display_stock = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you surround your code in script with $(function(){ /* jQuery code */ });  ? Adding this will ensure the script is executed only once the file is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving common CSS class to each row and apply it to the jQuery click function instead using `<tbody>` because `<tbody>` consists all the rows of the table.
Check out the following changes...

**HTML**

```
<tbody id="show_stocks">
    <tr class='myClass' id='101'>
      <td >Eliza</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='myClass' id='102'>
        <td >Lizzy</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myClass").click(function(evt) {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zduf8xbz/)

Comment: Thanks! This method worked well, but I had to include the jquery code in the php file where I echo the table instead of the other file with the html because of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should bind an event to a `td` and then get the closest `tr`.

Like this:

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  alert(id)
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="stock_table" class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Stock Name</th>
           <th>Ticker</th>
           <th>Invested</th>
           <th>Current Value</th>
           <th>Percent Change</th>
           <th>Sell</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="show_stocks">
        <tr id="aapl" class="">
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>Stock</td>
            <td>$90123</td>
            <td>$1990000</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qLdmsu9w/)